# Why can't I scrape using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I need to scrape the only table from this website: https://core.ap.gov.in/CMDashBoard/UserInterface/eAgriculture/eAgricultureVillagewise.aspx?mandal=Agali&district=Anantapuramu

I used beautiful soup and requests but not successful. Can you guys suggest me where I am going wrong?

```
mandal_url = "https://core.ap.gov.in/CMDashBoard/UserInterface/eAgriculture/eAgricultureVillagewise.aspx?mandal=Agali&district=Anantapuramu"
r = requests.get(mandal_url, verify=False).content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
df = pd.read_html(str(soup.find('table',{"id":"gvAgricultureVillage"})))
```

I am geeting 'Page not found' in the data frame. I don't know where I am going wrong!

Comment: break up your function so you can debug it more easily.  Does the `get` function return a 200?  what is the output of `soup.find(...)`, etc.

Comment: I am not getting the table values even in r ! and soup doesn't give me anything.

Comment: `get` function returns me some text. But there are not table values in that text

Answer (score 0):

The page likely requires some sort of sign-in. Viewing it myself by clicking on the link, I get [image: image shown].

You would need to add the cookies / some other headers to the request to appear "signed in".

Comment: I think the page is only accessible in India. Thank you for trying, though!

Comment: User Modelmat here is correct. I am currently in India, and I am unable to view the page too. You have to add specific headers and authorization configurations to the code for your use-case to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to click the link you're trying to scrape from an invalid link. When I click the link you provide, or the link you store in `mandal_url`, both return an 'Page not found' page. So you are scraping in the correct way, but the url you provide *to* the scraper is invalid/not up anymore.

Comment: Oh! It is working on my PC. I have clicked just now. I don't know. Maybe it is not accessible outside India.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get access to the website. But you can read form(s) on a webpage directly by using:

```
dfs = pd.read_html(your_url, header=0)
```

In the case that url requires authentication, you can get the form by:

```
r = requests.get(url_need_authentivation, auth=('myuser', 'mypasswd'))
pd.read_html(r.text, header=0)[1]
```

This will simplify your code. Hope it helps!